# How do I move a value from one table to another in the same workbook in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm doing a Controlled Assessment where I have to run a pet centre and I calculate the cost of keeping a number of dogs, but I want it so when the value changes in the first worksheet, it changes in the other worksheet, please tell me what to write in the formula bar.

I've tried `vlookup`, but that's only for formulas, so what can I do?

Thanks in advance!

[image: First screenshot]

[image: Second screenshot]

I've got my answer now, thanks to [this site.](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3767-excel-auto-copy-cell.html#a1)

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the first and the second worksheet?

Comment: Thanks, now can you please add which information from the first worksheet you want to have in your second worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in cell B4 of 'Overview':

```
=Animals!F4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enter in Column B OF Overview tab the formulas as shown in column D, as follows:

[image: Formulas to go in column B of overview sheet]